# Partial derivatives wrt total derivative and parametric relationship between them

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, parametric

I am studying a book called "A Student's Guide to Lagrangians and Hamiltonians".

There, they show a proof for this identity:

$$\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial \dot{q_j}} = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_j}$$

where:

- $x_i$ are Cartesian coordinates,
- $q_j$ are generalized coordinates,
- $v_i$ is velocity along $x_i$; that is $v_i = \frac{dx_i}{dt}$
- $\dot{q_j}$ is velocity along $q_j$; that is $v_i = \frac{dq_j}{dt}$

The proof is here and my two questions are placed in between the proof:

> ... $x_i$ is a function of the $q$s, so using the chain rule of differentiation we have $$v_i = \sum_{k} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k} \frac{dq_k}{dt} + \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t} = \sum_{k} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k} \dot{q_k} + \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t}$$
> We now obtain a very useful relation involving the partial derivative of $v_i$ with respect to $\dot{q_j}$ . Since a mixed second-order partial derivative does not depend on the order in which the derivatives are taken, we can write $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q_j}} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial \dot{q_j}}$$
> But $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial \dot{q_j}} = 0$ because $x$ does not depend on the generalized velocity $\dot{q}$.

**Question 1:** How is it that $x$ not dependent on $\dot{q}$? Cartesian coordinates are tied by their transformation to generalized coordinates, and generalized velocity is time derivative of generalized coordinates. They have a mathematical relationship. First, transform $x$ which must depend on time (that's why $v$ exists) , like $q=T(x(t))$ then take time derivative of it, and you have $\dot{q}$. Why does the book say they are independent? Is it because it is "partial" derivative and would not equal to zero for total derivative?

> Let us take the partial derivative of $v_i$ with respect to $\dot{q_j}$ ... This yields $$\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial \dot{q_j}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q_j}} \sum_{k} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k} \dot{q_k} + \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q_j}} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial t}$$ $$= \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q_j}} \sum_{k} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k} \dot{q_k} + 0$$ $$= \sum_{k} \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial \dot{q_j}} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k} \right) \dot{q_k} + \sum_{k} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k} \frac{\partial \dot{q_k}}{\partial \dot{q_j}}  = 0 + \sum_{k} \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_k} \delta _{ij}$$

**Question 1.5:** What does $\delta _{ij}$ mean? Delta generally means some difference but what does this specific use mean?

> $$ = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_j}$$
> Thus, we conclude that
> $$ \frac{\partial v_i}{\partial \dot{q_j}} = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_j}$$
> ... it is easy to remember because it states that the Cartesian velocity is related to the generalized velocity in the same way as the Cartesian coordinate is related to the generalized coordinate.

**Question 2:** I agree with the book on that this equality shows a nice relationship and also I think is intuitive. However, when I look at the same equality from this perspective
$$\frac{\partial \left( \frac{dx_i}{dt} \right)}{\partial \left( \frac{dq_j}{dt} \right)} = \frac{\partial x_i}{\partial q_j}$$
I feel like this shouldn't require any proof for it to work. I want to "cancel" $\frac{}{dt}$ parts of the equation. Because it feels like the derivative of parametric equations. But this uses partial derivatives so I am not sure.

Does my intuition make sense? Did we really needed that long proof?

Answer (score 1):

1. $x$ doesn't depend on $\dot q$ in the same manner as it doesn't depend on $x$. It is in a definition of a [holonomic system](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Holonomic_system) that is usually assumed in all those equations. Since the only constraints are of the form $f(x)=0$ / $F(q)=0$, the transformation $x=x(q)$ doesn't depend on $\dot q$. If it was, the system wouldn't be holonomic.
2. $\delta_{ij}$ is a [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta). In other words, it is n identity matrix in disguise. If you have a vector function,
   $$
   f_1(\dot q) = \dot q_1,\quad f_2(\dot q) = \dot q_2,\ldots\quad f_n(\dot q) = \dot q_n
   $$
   then the Jacobian of this system $\partial f_i/\partial \dot q_j$ is an identity matrix.
3. Your intuition does make sense in holonomic systems. However, generally, it's not true, when there are non-integratable constraints involving velocities.